# Routing of incoming calls by called number

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

I have two phone numbers registered with the same sip provider.  I would like Asterisk/PJSIP to route phone #1 (18005551212) differently than phone #2 (18005551313).

```
[sipprovider-18005551212]
type=registration
client_uri=sip:18005551212@sip.provider.com:5060

[sipprovider-18005551313]
type=registration
client_uri=sip:18005551313@sip.provider.com:5060
```

The Contact provided by Asterisk during registration is the same for both (using default extension 's').

```
Contact: <sip:s@10.1.1.1:5060>;expires=120
```

Can I do any of the following:

1)  When registering, provide an extension other than 's'?  Allowing inbound calls to hit unique extensions in the dialplan.

2) Route to unique context based on the To: Header on the INVITE?  (which holds the unique phone number called).  I have tried using 'context=' in the pjsip.conf endpoint block, but no luck; routing is either by IP (which is the same for both phone numbers), or by name (which is based on the From: Header).

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this from my `extensions.conf`

```
[inbound-sip]
exten => 3215445,1,Goto(sip-in-1,s,1)
exten => 2544221,1,Goto(sip-in-2,s,1)

[sip-in-1]
exten => s,1,Goto(internal-ext,6881,1)
```

Calls then end up in the relevant context for further processing and alerting etc. `sip-in-1` or `sip-in-2` in this case.

In your `sip.conf` or `pjsip.conf` you need to specify the inbound context for both numbers you have - in this case `context = inbound-sip`

Comment: Tried this without success; context inbound-sip is entered, but with extension 's'.  So call fails because 's' is not a valid extension.  Any idea how to get the called phone number to be used as the extension number?

Comment: Yep - just tested with `s` and get the same. Where do you want the calls to end up, or what call flow do you expect? You get a call on 3215445 and want it to go to line 1 on a phone and when you get a call from 2544221 to line 2? I don't use `s` in my sip dial plan only for pstn lines.

Comment: No phones are dialed directly.  One number to an auto-attendant style dialplan, the other to an AGI() execution.  So as long as I can hit different dialplan entry points, I am good.

Comment: updated my answer - try that - it works here without an invalid extension error.

Comment: Same problem; no 's' extension found.

Comment: can you post your full extensions.conf and sip.conf relevent sections (mask any sensitive numbers/passwords etc & I'll have a look tomorrow for you. Also which version of asterisks are you running?

Comment: I ended up modifying your idea; In the dialplan I use the "To:" SIP header, extract the phone number from it, and use GotoIf() type of logic.  It works.  I am not happy that PJSIP can't route better, and this type of dialplan has to be used.  Thank you for helping; I will mark the answer useful, but not accepted (as the offered solution doesn't work for me).  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should enable sip debug and see if calls have anything like destination number.

If it have no - you have no way get info which not present.

If you have, you should create extension s and parse number info using SIP_HEADER function from sip request body.

Comment: Yes, this is the approach that was taken.  The destination number was in the "To:" Header.  Extension s handles the call, and PJSIP_HEADER() is used to read the "To:" header, and parse the destination number.  I was surprised that PJSIP was not able to better route by destination number.